# how to cast a string as a getpass.getpass() string in python

Tags: python, telethon

there's a function which called getpass which asks you to provide a password inside a input() and then it returns the password.

I'm trying to cast a string as a getpass object. without using an input.

I'm communicating with [telethon api](https://docs.telethon.dev/)

Whenever I try to use anormal string as my password I endup with the message "Couldn't login"
you can view the code here:

```
try:
     obj.client.sign_in(obj.user.phone, code = code)
except SessionPasswordNeededError:
     try:
         obj.client.sign_in(password=obj.client.cloud)
     except:
         print("Couldn't log")
```

But when I use

```
try:
     obj.client.sign_in(obj.user.phone, code = code)
except SessionPasswordNeededError:
     try:
          passw = getpass.getpass()
          obj.client.sign_in(password=passw)
     except:
          print("Couldn't log")
```

I get no exception and all is working good.
therefore I know getpass is not returning a normal string and I need to cast my string to a getpass object

Is there any option to do that?

Thanks in advance!

------Edit------

as @Chris mentioned in the comments, getpass returns a normal string. The problem was with the "obj.client.cloud" it had a line break inside of it that's why when I've printed both strings I thought they were the same.

You can check the object type using type(obj) as @Chris pointed.
and you can check if both are the same using ("string" == getpass.getpass()) and it will return if true.

Comment: `getpass.getpass()` returns a regular string. There is nothing to cast. Try it yourself: run `type(passw)`. I suspect `obj.client.cloud` doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: @Chris I think you were right, probably obj.client.cloud is the problem.
It's weird because whenever I print the obj.client.cloud it returns the correct cloud password, But it isn't working. If I type the password directly it works.

Comment: Okay, after checking there was a line break inside the string and that's what caused the exception. @Chris thanks for your help !